# how can i import CoreText framework into xcode 3.1.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am using xcode 3.1.4 and i want to use CoreText framework how can i do this.
i tried to import applicationServices framework but the code didn't run

Answer (score 1):

CoreText.framework was added in iPhone SDK 3.2

> Core Text is an advanced, low-level technology for laying out text and
>   handling fonts. It is designed for high performance and ease of use.
>   The Core Text API, introduced in Mac OS X v10.5, is accessible from
>   all Mac OS X application environments. **It is also available in iOS
>   3.2.**

More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH1-SW1

Comment: so i will not be able to use CoreText until i upgrade my xcode

Comment: Exactly, there's no other way. I hope this answers your question. (=

Comment: Great! Maybe you should put your question as answered.